# How to write the integral $\int_R 5(x+y)\ dy\ dx$ where $R$ is the region bounded by $y=\frac{1}{7}x$, $x=6$ and the $x$-axis?

Tags: integration

I have the integral $$\int_R 5(x+y)\ dy\ dx$$ where the region $R$ is bounded by $y=\frac{1}{7}x$, $x=6$ and the $x$-axis.

I don't know how to write this problem exactly.

Could anyone edit my equation and solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the y-values extend from $0$ to the line $y = \dfrac{x}{7}$. The x-value go from the x-axis to $6$. So we end up with the double integral: $$\int\int_{R} 5(x+y)\mathrm{d}A = \int_0^6\int_0^{x/7} 5(x+y)\; \mathrm{d}y \; \mathrm{d}x $$

---

When wanting to determine bounds like this I find it easy to draw the region of integration, $R$, then look how $y$ values vary and how $x$ values vary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

To solve this kind of problems it's useful to represent the region. Can you do this? ( it's simply a rectangular triangle with a vertex in the origin, one other in $(6,0)$ and the hypotenuse on the straight line $y=\dfrac{x}{7}$). So the integral become:
$$
\int _0^6\int_0^{x/7}5(x+y)dy dx
$$